# Ext JS Form in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, extjs

I'm trying an Ext JS 3 form in an ASP.NET page but my form is loaded outside the "BodyContent" of my ASP page. I've tried: renderTo: Ext.get('BodyContent') but it's not working.
My asp page with the Ext code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Forms" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Forms.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExtJSDemo.Forms" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL.substr(0, 5) != 'data:') {
            Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'ext-3.4.0/resources/images/default/s.gif';
        }
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            var movie_form = new Ext.FormPanel({
                url: 'movie-form-submit.aspx',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                frame: true,
                title: 'Movie Information Form',
                width: 250,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Title',
                    name: 'title'
                },{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Director',
                    name: 'director'
                },{
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Released',
                    name: 'released'
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<!-- I'M EXPECTING MY FORM HERE, BUT IT'S LOADED OUTSIDE BodyContent AT THE BOTTOM OF THE ENTIRE PAGE -->
</asp:Content>
```

When I use the renderTo: Ext.get('BodyContent') my form is completely not shown!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that "BodyContent" is not a vaild id in result page html.

Try putting an empty div

```
<div id="myform"></div>
```

inside "BodyContent" content placeholder and change form configuration to render inside that div:

`renderTo: 'myform'`